# Element already child of other element error in Silverlight User Control

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I've placed some UIElements in a row of the grid at different column positions, now I have a + button if I click on that a new row containing same UIElements should be added below the first row. but it gives me error like "Element is already child of other element".

How can i get rid of this error. I need to add an duplicate copy(new reference) of the control below it in the new row. how can i do it?
Any help would be appreciated....

Thanks,
Gk Prajapati

Comment: Some xaml and code-behind would be helpful.  Do you have any duplicate IDs in the xaml?  When your write, ".. same UIElements should be added below...", I assume you mean the same type of elements.

Comment: WELL.sorry I didn't provided any sample but idea is fairly simple..I have a row  of controls in the grid control and at the end of the row there is a + button. on the click of the + button I want to Add one more row(duplicate-duplicating each UIelement present in column) under the previous row.

Comment: I dont have duplicates IDs.....I want to create duplicate UIElements at run time- On + button click.

Comment: It's hard to figure out where your error is coming from without being able to see the code that is producing it.  Here is a sample app that, I think, does roughly what you are trying to do:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7645606/SO2.zip