# Silverlight User Control Issue

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to create a Repeater Template User Control i.e. a rectangular border contains a row of UIElements Like TextBox, ComboBox etc and then I'm automatically adding a + button at the end of the Row. On + button Click I want to add the Same duplicate row below it.

This is the Syntax making use of User Control:

```
<RepeaterTemplate>
 <RepeaterTemplateItem>
  <TextBox />
  <ComboBox />
 </RepeaterTemplateItem>
</RepeaterTemplate>
```

CODE BEHIND:

RepeaterLayoutItem:

Public Grid RepeaterRow { get; set; }
  Public List LayoutItemCollection { get; set; }

//On + button click handler:

RepeaterLayoutItem duplicate = this.memberWiseClone();
 LayoutItemCollection.Add(duplicate);

RepeaterLayout : 
  public ObservableCollection Children { get; set; }
  public Grid RepeaterContentGrid { get; set; }

foreach(RepeaterLayoutItem item in Children)
 {
   Grid duplicateRow = item.RepeaterRow;

RepeaterContentGrid.Children.Add(duplicateRow); //Here it gives error "Element is already child of other element" on + button click.

}

I also tried it with ICloneable interface, but still same issue.

If I duplicate the row using the memberWiseClone(), still on adding the duplicate row I'm getting the same error. May be bceause of non-null value of Parent property in the cloned duplicate row.

I don't know how to get this functionality working. Please HELP.

Thanks,
GK Prajapati

Comment: Can you show the code-behind that creates and adds the new row?

Comment: An edit to question is made, showing the code behind.

Comment: Did you look at the sample I offered in a comment to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251809/element-already-child-of-other-element-error-in-silverlight-user-control#comment30322148_20251809 ?

Comment: Where does memberWiseClone() come from?